# Images are moving after transition is done

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website and I'm using Bootstrap for a slider on the top of the page. The only problem is that after the transition is done the images move up by about 100px and makes the whole website look bad. You can see my code pen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYYgOj

```
<header id="headerCarousel" class="carousel slide" date-ride="carousel" data-interval="300000000">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>

  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" style="background:url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/keyboard_apple_black_white_backlit_31066_3840x2400.jpg) center center fixed; background-size:cover;    background-position: 0 0;">
      TEXT
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="background:url(http://itop.freewallpaper-s.net/wp-content/uploads/wallpapers/Home-office-macbookair-apple-brand-notebook-computer-top-uhd-4k-wallpapers-2560x1440.jpg) center center fixed; background-size:cover;    background-position: 0 0;">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#headerCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#headerCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `background-position: 0 0;"` along with `fixed`, you all ready have it declared with `center center`.

See this > [CSS background-position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#headerCarousel").carousel();
 });
```

```css
.carousel-inner .item {
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header id="headerCarousel" class="carousel slide" date-ride="carousel" data-interval="300000000">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" style="background:url(http://placehold.it/2350x800/f00/fff) center center; background-size:cover;"></div>
    <div class="item" style="background:url(http://placehold.it/2350x800/000/fff) center center; background-size:cover;"></div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#headerCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#headerCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</header>
```